# PHP register_shutdown_function on IIS 8.5 firing on same request

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am running into a few issues with getting some code run in the background on windows. I am trying to run a large processing request (sending emails) in the background and I am using the following

```
 register_shutdown_function(array(__CLASS__, "consume_on_shutdown"));
```

to start the process once the request is done. This works well on my Mac but when I try and do it on windows it executes immediately on the same request so it hangs for ages. Has anyone run into issues similar?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php

Answer (score 1):

`register_shutdown_function` does not guarantee the connection will be closed before the shutdown function is executed. As you're seeing on Windows, it's holding the connection to the client open until after your script and the shutdown function have both executed.

If you need to run on Windows, your best options are to send it to a scheduler or launch a separate thread, neither of which are easily portable to non-Windows operating systems for code portability.